# Failover all cluster roles at once

Tags: file-sharing, failovercluster

I'm setting up a failover cluster on Azure 2019 VMs.  I've got to set up both a file server and a generic service.  Ideally I'd like to always move them both to the same node rather than having to do it individually.  Is there a way of grouping these together so when one role moves so does the other?

I'm not seeing any options in the GUI or within powershell but I might just not know what to look for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to combine different cluster roles to failover together, you need to organize them into a single cluster group. Here is the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/mscs/groups) in this regard.

Usually, those kinds of management tasks are not present within the Failover Cluster Manager and have to be done using [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/failoverclusters/add-clustergroup). If Powershell commands do not work for you right away, please make sure you are running them as administrator and that Powershell is [configured correctly](https://www.hyper-v.io/powershell-commands-scripts-not-work-can-fix/).